# Erro em busca simples no Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Estou tentando realizar uma busca simples. Ao colocar `dd($clientes)` no método search ele está retornando o resultado da busca corretamente, mas ao retornar para a view da o erro:

> Trying to get property of non-object (View:
>   /var/www/html/neowix/resources/views/clientes/index.blade.php)

*View:*

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">Clientes</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="/clientes/create" role="button">Incluir</a>
                </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->

                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <form action="/clientes/search" method="get" class="form-inline">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="palavraChave" id="campo_busca" placeholder="Nome ou CNPJ">
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Buscar</button>
                    </form>
                </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->

            </div><!-- /.row -->
        </div>
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <tr>
                <th>CNPJ</th>
                <th>Razão Social</th>
                <th>Nome Fantasia</th>
                <th>Alterar</th>
                <th>Excluir</th>
            </tr>
            @foreach($clientes as $value)
                <tr>
                  <td class="cnpj">{{$value->cnpj}}</td>
                  <td>{{$value->razao_social}}</td>
                  <td>{{$value->nome_fantasia}}</td>
                  <td>
                    <a href="/clientes/edit/{{$value->id}}" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></a>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <a href="/clientes/destroy/{{$value->id}}" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></a>
                  </td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach     
        </table>

        <nav aria-label="...">
          <ul class="pager">
            <li><a href="#">Anterior</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Próxima</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection

@section('javascript')
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.cnpj').mask('00.000.000/0000-00');
});
</script>
@endsection
```

*Controller:*

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
    $palavraChave = $request->input('palavraChave');
    $clientes = DB::table('clientes')->where('razao_social', $palavraChave)->first();
    return view('/clientes/index', ['clientes' => $clientes]);
}
```

Comment: Qual o código da sua view? Acho que está acessando o valor de um array como se fosse um objeto

Comment: O código da view esta ai em cima. Não coloquei completo, sá a parte que acredito que importa.

Comment: Nesse caso, a parte onde você chama a variável clientes seria a mais importante

Comment: Coloquei a view inteira.

Comment: Marcelo, que bom que resolveu seu problema, mas ao perguntar coloque apenas os trechos de código referentes ao problema, fica mais fácil identificar uma solução

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema alterando de first() para get() no método:

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
$palavraChave = $request->input('palavraChave');
$clientes = DB::table('clientes')->where('razao_social', $palavraChave)->first();
return view('/clientes/index', ['clientes' => $clientes]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tente fazer o seguinte:

```
public function index()
{
    $clientes = new Cliente();
    return view('clientes.index', [
        "clientes" => $clientes->all()
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Não acontece nada nem da erro. Só atualiza a pagina.

Comment: @Marcelo adicione o dd($clientes->all()) no metodo, veja se tem registros

Comment: Sim, ele retorna os dois registros que existem no banco.

Comment: Então o problema está na view

Comment: Sim, mas ele retorna os dois registros, sendo que deveria retornar somente o que fiz na busca. No código do meu metodo ele está retornando o registro que eu fiz na busca, o problema esta sendo esse erro quando seria para retornar para a view.

Comment: @Marcelo o problema pode ser que você está tentando redirecionar para uma url em vez da view, tente usar o metodo `return redirect('/clientes/index')->with('cliente', $cliente);`, pode funcionar, mas não é o ideal.

Comment: Permanece na mesma página. Dei um dd($clientes) e ele esta retornando o registro correto como disse.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53197/discussion-between-felipe-paetzold-and-marcelo).

Answer (score 0):

Tenta usar:

`$clientes = DB::table('clientes')->where('clientes.razao_social', $palavraChave)->first();`

e depois dá dd() logo embaixo em `$clientes`:

`dd($clientes);`

e vê o que retorna pra você..

Comment: Ele retorna: Undefined variable: palavraChave No caso, no meu código ao dar o dd($clientes) ele retorna o cliente que fiz a busca, meu problema é está sendo mandar esse resultado para a view.